# Under tcsh shell, how to send the output of the script to a program either on shell and on gdb?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am working on remote computer. The shell is tcsh with no root privileges. I have no control on the server.

I have a script script.pl. When running it:

```
perl script.pl
```

gives the correct results

but when I'm trying to send this output to some program I got an error "Illegal variable name."

```
./vuln $(perl script.pl)
Illegal variable name.
```

When i'm working on gdb, the error of course repeats

```
(gdb) r $(perl script.pl)
Starting program: /vuln $(perl script.pl)
Illegal variable name.
```

How to send the output of the script to the program either on shell and gdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcsh does not understand this substitution syntax $(...)
You need to use backticks for portable shell scripts:

```
./vuln `perl script.pl`
```

Comment: Thanks, that make the job!